# How to return a file with image content in php?

Tags: php

So I have a php file that takes in a image file and returns a image file back. The problem is that it returns a cluster of characters when I was expecting a file. How do I fix this? Sorry I am new to Php.

So I set the content type in the header and use this method imagejpeg($newImage);

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$newSize = $_POST['newSize'];
if(empty($newSize)){
    header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
    exit();
}
$extension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'));
$imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

switch($extension){
    case '.jpg':
    case '.jpeg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case '.gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case '.png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    default:
        header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
        exit('');
}

$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newSize, $newSize);

if(empty($newImage) || empty($image)){
    header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
    exit();
}

imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newSize, $newSize, $imageInfo[0], $imageInfo[1]);

header('Content-Type: ' . $imageInfo['mime']);

switch($extension){
    case '.jpg':
    case '.jpeg':
        imagejpeg($newImage);
        break;
    case '.gif':
        imagegif($newImage);
        break;
    case '.png':
        imagepng($newImage);
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`.... should work for you? otherwise show us your code please.

Comment: Post _all_ of the actual code. Edit your question.

Comment: set the correct header, then `echo file_get_contents ($filename)`

Comment: @GordonM It is not a file in the file system.

Comment: So the scenario is that I need this php to resize a image and then return it to the browser. It's sort of doing that but the return response is a a bunch of jumbled characters.

Comment: What exactly do you want? A file download or the image displayed in the browser?

Comment: Well im using Parse.com as my backend. I need file back so that I can upload it to Parse.

Comment: `Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 24 Jan 2013 09:41:17 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=78
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4` this is what the response header looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this could work. It will initialize a file download. If the code you posted is your own, you should unerstand my additions to it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$newSize = $_POST['newSize'];
if(empty($newSize)){
    header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
    exit();
}
$extension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'));
$imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

switch($extension){
    case '.jpg':
    case '.jpeg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case '.gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case '.png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    default:
        header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
        exit('');
}

$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newSize, $newSize);

header('Content-Type: '.$_FILES['image']['type']);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image'.$extension.'"');

switch($extension){
    case '.jpg':
    case '.jpeg':
        imagejpg($newImage);
        break;
    case '.gif':
        imagegif($newImage);
        break;
    case '.png':
        imagepng($newImage);
        break;
}

if(empty($newImage) || empty($image)){
    header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Well, beside that, it can't even work, because you only create a black image w/o the content, you wanted to resize. You should definetely check some tutorials. Regearding your mentioned issue. Just try to set the `headers` AFTER using imagepng/jpg/gif etc.